# How to make my Bot Private Message the user who has been kicked by the bot ? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "kick")) {
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Staff");
    if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)) {
        message.author.sendMessage(`some insulting stuff...`)
        message.mentions.users.map(member => {
        message.guild.member(member).kick().catch(console.error);})
```

How do I edit this code to make it send a Private Message to the kicked user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a line to your map to attempt to send a message to the user before kicking them:

```
message.mentions.users.map(async user => {
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    try { await user.send('kicked'); }
    catch (err) { console.log('failed to kick user'); }
    member.kick();
});
```

Sometimes this will fail if the user has DMs disabled, but there's not much of a workaround.